# Joined lines at certain angles have pointed vertexes instead of rounded

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawing, core-graphics, angle

My app allows you to draw using a variety of tools. One of them lets you make an angle: you tap three times, then an angle is drawn for you. Unfortunately, it gets really pointy but then rounded again at certain angles for some reason. I'm using

```
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
```

Here is a picture to exemplify what I'm talking about:

[image]

Does anyone know what causes this or how to fix it so it is round all the time??

For the most part, all I do is:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, first.x, first.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, second.x, second.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, third.x, third.y);
```

then stroke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's controlled by your line join style, not your line cap style.

```
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
```

The default line join style is miter, and it looks like you're hitting the miter limit, which is why it becomes round at some angle. (See [CGContextSetMiterLimit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kCGLineJoinMiter)).

Comment: You're the best! I checked the docs but I rolled right over this. Thanks a bunch!